# Formal proof of limit of chain of nested sets towards empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a countable collection of mutually disjoint sets $A_1, A_2,...$, I would like to utilize the Axiom of Continuity for the sake of completing some other proof. If we let $B_k=\bigcup_{i=k}^\infty A_i$, then the fact that $B_{i+1}\subset B_{i}$ is trivial. But now to utilize the axiom we also have to establish that $B_k \downarrow \emptyset$ (the limit of the infinite sequence $B_1\supset B_2\supset B_3\supset \cdots$ is $\emptyset$), which is easy to see intuitively. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a formal argument to why this is true. Any tips?

Comment: I believe you mean $B_{i+1}\subset B_i$. What is the definition of $B_k\downarrow\varnothing$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction. Also added clarification for that notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x\in B_k$ for all $k$.  In particular, then, $x\in B_1=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$.  So, there exists some $i$ such that $x\in A_i$.  Now can you find a value of $k$ such that $x\not\in B_k$, to reach a contradiction?

More details are hidden below.

> Since the sets $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint, $x\in A_i$ implies $x\not\in A_j$ for all $j\neq i$.  In particular, $x\not\in A_j$ for all $j\geq i+1$, and thus $x\not\in B_{i+1}$.  This contradicts the assumption that $x\in B_k$ for all $k$, and thus no such $x$ exists.  That is, $\bigcap B_k=\emptyset$.

Comment: From my understanding, you're assuming for the sake of contradiction that the limit is not true, in which case we must have $B_k$ nonempty for all $k$. That means for all $k$, there exists some $x_k\in B_k$; that is each $B_k$ has some element $x_k$, which I call $x_k$ instead of $x$ since it need not be the same for all $k$. The nested structure ensures that each $x_k\in B_j$ for $j < k$ as well, but doesn't guarantee for $j>k$. So how can we guarantee that such an $x$ exists such that $x\in B_k$ for all $k$ (your original assumption)?

Comment: No.  The limit is the intersection $\bigcap_k B_k$, and so to say it is not empty means that there exists $x$ such that for all $k$, $x\in B_k$.  This is much stronger than saying each $B_k$ is individually nonempty.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there some formal justification for why the limit is the intersection (it makes sense intuitively)?

Comment: Usually, that is just the *definition* of the limit of a decreasing sequence of sets.  Do you have a different definition?

Comment: I see, actually I wasn't aware of the theory of limits of sets (I'm working off a book on statistics which doesn't introduce it), but after your comment and some research I have a much better picture of the definitions. I didn't have a clear definition in mind for the limit of the decreasing chain before. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know the definition of something, you can't possibly prove anything about it, since you don't know what the statement you are trying to prove means!  So, you should not have even attempted to solve your problem without first figuring out what the definition is.

Comment: Seriously, this is a **really big mistake** you have made that you need to learn from.  If you are trying to prove things without knowing the relevant definitions, there is a fundamental problem with how you are thinking about math.

Comment: This is true, thank you for the advice!